# Can a UIPopoverController be moved around the screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, animation, uipopovercontroller

Is it possible to move a UIPopovercontroller around the screen once its already been presented?
   I have a small view in my app that can move slightly, and I would like a UIPopoverController to move around with it without having to re-present the UIPopoverController every time it moves.  Is this possible?

Comment: Isn't `[popover presentPopoverFromRect:]` working for you?

Comment: The question is whether he can move the popOver once it's been presented

Comment: I don't think it's position can be directly changed.  However, if you call presentPopoverFromRect on it without dismissing it, it should "move".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS 9, "UIPopoverController is deprecated. Popovers are now implemented as UIViewController presentations. Use a modal presentation style of UIModalPresentationPopover and UIPopoverPresentationController."

Use the following to present a popover. You may be able to change the values of sourceRect and sourceView but this isn't intended API behavior.

```
    DetailViewController *detailVC = self.detailViewController;
    detailVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(420, 92);
    detailVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;


    UIPopoverPresentationController *presController = detailVC.popoverPresentationController;
    if (presController) {
        presController.delegate = detailVC;
        presController.barButtonItem = self.detailButton;
        presController.sourceRect = self.view.frame;
        presController.sourceView = self.view;
        presController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
    }

    [self presentViewController: detailVC animated:YES completion:^{

    }];
```

Instead, I suggest keeping a reference to the view controller presented with the popover, dismiss the popover and re-present.

```
DetailViewController *detailVC = self.detailViewController;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

    UIPopoverPresentationController *presController = detailVC.popoverPresentationController;
    if (presController) {
        presController.delegate = detailVC;
        presController.barButtonItem = self.detailButton;
        presController.sourceRect = self.view.frame; //Update frame
        presController.sourceView = self.view;
        presController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
    }

    [self presentViewController: detailVC animated:NO completion:^{

    }];
}];
```

Comment: I keep getting down voted for this. If you're going to down vote this accepted answer, be helpful and leave a comment.

Comment: "Create your own" is not the answer i would be looking for

Comment: @Loukas I hope you'll like the new answer better. If UIPopoverPresentationController doesn't provide the needed functionality, you'll have to recreate UIPopoverController as the API isn't very flexible.

Comment: Not sure you need to "keep a reference": `UIViewController` already has a `presentedViewController` property.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-call presentPopoverFromRect.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1694/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.  This is no method to do that.

```
pover presentPopoverFromRect:
```

was mentioned in the comments, but notice the

> present

you cannot represent without redrawing.

Comment: Pease see Paper by Fifty on iPad. They have a popover that contains a text field. The popover animated above the keyboard and when the keyboard is dismissed, it animated back to original position. Is the build in or developer enduced?

Comment: When a keyboard appears, by default the SDK will move the popover higher to accommodate the keyboard.  Once the keyboard is dismissed, the popover will animate back to its original location.  This is all built in behavior.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I forgot what my point was with my comment, was too long ago now.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the users touches around the screen, and use `presentPopoverFromRect:` to reshow the popover.

Comment: That's worth a try, but I imagine that it might be a little expensive to do it that way.  I am sure that when you dismiss it and reshow it, there is a lot allocation of the resources that is going on that could be quite taxing to the system.

Comment: This is true, but thats where good memory management comes into play. Especially with the iPad, you have a little but more memory to play with.